# How to create ConfigObject using only nested maps in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, dsl, spring-dsl

It is possible to implement closure-based config as a map of maps?

```
grails {
  acme {
     host = 'localhost'
     poolSettings {
        timeout = 5000
     }
  }
}
```

The above config is convention for a grails plugin. We're doing a migration, and due to legacy constraints, we need to create the config dynamically to eliminate impact to legacy code.

I started with a simple config:

```
grails.acme = [host:'localhost']
```

This works fine with the plugin on startup, so I added a nested map:

```
grails.acme = [host:'localhost']
def poolProps = //do some work to get pool settings
grails.acme << [poolSettings:poolProps]
```

On startup I pretty print `grails.acme`:

```
{
    "host": "locahost",
    "poolSettings": {
        "timeout": 5000
    }
}
```

It looks normal, but soon after the acme plugin fails with the following error:

> 2014-09-27 23:27:07,460 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: No
>   signature of method: AcmePlugin$_closure2_closure5_closure9 .doCall()
>   is applicable for argument types: (grails.spring.BeanBuilder) values:
>   [grails.spring.BeanBuilder@7b067fd7] Possible solutions:
>   doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(),
>   call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object),
>   call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll() Message: No
>   signature of method:
>   AcmeGrailsPlugin$_closure2_closure5_closure9.doCall() is applicable
>   for argument types: (grails.spring.BeanBuilder) values:
>   [grails.spring.BeanBuilder@7b067 fd7] Possible solutions:
>   doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(),
>   call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object),
>   call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)

I'm sort of stumped on this, I'm assuming it's not possible, and I'm not sure how to even approach the closure-based convention dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One  problem with your code might be that the config node structure looks perfectly all right, but in fact isn't. I.e. that some nodes are `Map` instances, but not `ConfigObject` instances.

In most cases this probably won't matter, but in your case it seems that a 3rd party plugin fails with some ugly and incomprehensible exception.

I'm unable to recreate your problem, so I can't say for sure whether this is the real problem that you've encountered, nor whether the suggested solution fix your problem. Nevertheless, my first attempt would be to fix the types so that all nodes in the configuration tree are of type `ConfigObject`. Something like this:

```
def poolProps = [timeout: 5000] as ConfigObject // convert type to ConfigObject
grails.acme.host = 'localhost'
grails.acme << [ poolSettings : poolProps ]
```

Note that if the maps you create (poolProps in this case) contains nested map elements, you would have to convert those as well.

Comment: I was trying this on the grails redis plugin, 1.5.5, in case you wanted to attempt reproducing, replace acme with redis, lol, I'll try your suggestion, i

Comment: I created a similar answer just for clarity that Grails is not necessary. Credits to @Steiner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497150/how-to-create-a-dsl-groovy-config-file-using-only-raw-maps-and-lists

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible,  actually

```
grails {
   acme {
      host = 'localhost'
      poolSettings {
         timeout = 5000
      }
   }
}
```

is the same as:

```
grails.acme.host = 'localhost'
grails.acme.poolSettings.timeout = 5000
```

the closures are just syntactic sugar. You can even combine both types:

```
grails.acme {
   host = 'localhost'
   poolSettings.timeout = 5000
}
```